# Web API 2 Basic Auth: Why use a filter or message handler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Web API 2 service behind Basic NTLM authentication. I can get JSON results back from the service just fine without having any Message Handler or Filters set up.

If I don't need to do anything other than ensure that the request is authenticated, do I still need to implement an Authentication Message Handler or Filter?

What are some use cases for supporting a Message Handler or Filter?

Thanks!

Comment: Modules restrict before hitting the route and both handlers and filters make sure user is authenticated before respective action executed. Modules are not web hosting agnostic. If you needs host agnostic and authenticated earlier than just before action execution choose handlers.

Comment: I dont think you need Authentication Message / Filter handler as long as you are making sure requests are authenticated.